# VB.net calculus from stopwatch return negative minutes

Tags: vb.net, time, logic, stopwatch

the number of **seconds** is shown **negative** when the stopwatch works for about 15 minutes and on.

```
Dim timeTook As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew

'Some time-consuming tasks

timeTook.Stop()

Dim mins As Long = CLng(timeTook.Elapsed.TotalMinutes.ToString) \ 1
Dim secs As Long = CLng(timeTook.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString) \ 1 - 60 * mins
Label3.Text = "Time took: " & mins & " Minutes and " & secs & " Seconds"
```

This is maybe something about the timer or a logic error, but it looks logic to me. I can't figure out what does not work, please help.

Comment: Why are you converting values to `Long` and then parsing them? Why aren't you just using `timeTook.Elapsed.Minutes` and `timeTook.Elapsed.Seconds`? It would really help if you'd dump `timeTook.Elapsed.ToString()`, and also tell us what values you're seeing.

Comment: Are you sure it is the minutes that is negative not seconds? From your code, I would guess your seconds are showing as negative.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much more readable and efficient if you just did it like this:

```
Dim timeTook As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew
'Some time-consuming tasks
timeTook.Stop()
Label3.Text = "Time took: " & Math.Floor(timeTook.Elapsed.TotalMinutes).ToString() & " Minutes and " & timeTook.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString() & " Seconds"
```

Or better yet:

```
Label3.Text = "Time took: " & timeTook.Elapsed.ToString()
```

The `Elapsed` property already has all the information you need, so it's silly, and more error prone, for you to recalculate it all yourself.

Comment: I think `timeTook.Elapsed.Seconds` has to be `timeTook.Elapsed.Seconds Mod 60`. So that it will show mins and remaining seconds.

Comment: `timeTook.Elapsed.Seconds` will never be more than 59.  You're thinking of `timeTook.Elapsed.TotalSeconds`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the CLng() function *rounds* a floating point value.  So if the elapsed time is, say, 0.6 minutes then you'll get mins = 1.  Your *secs* value is now going to be negative.

You need to *truncate* the value so it is always rounded down.  Let's get rid of the string conversion as well, that doesn't make sense:

```
Dim mins = Math.Truncate(timeTook.Elapsed.TotalMinutes)
Dim secs = timeTook.Elapsed.TotalSeconds - 60 * mins
Label3.Text = String.Format("Time took: {0:N0} minutes and {1:N0} seconds", _
                            mins, secs)
```

I'll leave the pluralization bug up to you to fix :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is the minutes that is negative not seconds? Your code

```
Dim secs As Long = CLng(timeTook.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString) \ 1 - 60 * mins
```

will always return negative because `any number / negative number is negative`.

Better way

```
Dim secs As Long = timeTook.Elapsed.TotalSeconds mod 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use .ToString with format?

```
    Label3.text = timeTook.Elapsed.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
```